# Restrict user from closing tabs or window of browser

Tags: javascript

How do I restrict my user from closing the tabs or browser while accessing any specific page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {

  if (!e) e = window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?';
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return 'You sure you want to leave?';
  return false;
}
```

I tried above code but it gives popup for leave the page or stay on the page on chrome browser.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

The browser is software that belongs to the user. It is completely under their control. If they want to quit, they can quit.

You need to design your system so it is robust enough to handle people quitting part way through.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but is there any way so that if users on certain page of my webapp i control them no to close browser until they submit their form or other stuff?

Comment: @RahulTrlIt — I refer you back to the very first sentence of my answer. And the rest of it. It's a short answer and every part of it addresses that question.